# How to print collection mysql query in magento

Tags: debugging, magento

Let's say I have a collection like:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ...
            ->load();
```

How do I print the actual MySQL code that gets executed?

Comment: This is the correct answer, right here. `echo $collection->getSelectSql(true);`

Comment: Correction to my original comment. It should be ```echo $collection->load()->getSelectSql(true)```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can always view your sql query at a certain point by echoing getSelect as shown:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection();
echo $products->getSelect();
```

To change query parameters you want to check out methods like:

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect('someattribute');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('someattribute', array('eq'=>'1'));
```

Comment: The problem with your answer Nick is that when you start adding attributes or custom columns or other things, echoing $collection->getSelect() does not take those additions into account. You have to load the collection first like this `echo $collection->load()->getSelect()`. Its cleaner to use `echo $collection->getSelectSql(true)`

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, it still doesn't include other attributes from the query.

Comment: @user1240207 - yes, i just realized you need to call ```->load()``` before running $collection->getSelectSql(true). The attributes get added to the query when the collection is loaded.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson, hmm, that's odd. I've made a few tests, $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('price')->addAttributeToSelect('cost')->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('notnull' => true))->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('neq' => '')); $collection->load(); 
print_r($collection->getSelectSql(true)."\n"); Only the special_price made it to the query.

Comment: @user1240207 I just ran a little test. You either need to use $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*') or $collection->joinAttribute( 'price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $storeId );

Answer (score 14):

You can print collection using below code:
We can print query of collection using `getSelect()->__toString()`

```
$products = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)
 ->addAttributeToFilter(‘status’, array(‘eq’ => 1));
echo $products->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Have you seen http://kuldipchudasama.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/magento-print-query-of-collection/?
    This works well.

Answer (score 7):

Most other answers here say that `$products->getSelect()` will do it - this is fine if all you're going to do with it is `echo`, but in fact `getSelect()` doesn't just return a string, it returns a Varien_Db_Select object.

Invoking `echo` on that object automatically triggers its `__toString()` method, so you just get the SQL string, but try passing it to `Mage::log()` and you'll get a lot more than you expected.

If you just want to log the SQL, you can use:

```
Mage::log($products->getSelect()->__toString());
```

Or how about using the object's own:

```
$products->printLogQuery(false, true); // don't echo, do log
```

`printLogQuery` is defined in lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php.

Answer (score 3):

You can print

```
$products->getSelect()->assemble();
```

Comment: I don't even think you need the `assemble()`, just `echo $products->getSelect();`

Answer (score 3):

I work with collections every day. This is without a doubt the correct way.

`echo $collection->getSelectSql(true);`

Answer (score 2):

If you simple set the first parameter of `->load()` to `true`, like so:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ...
           ->load(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2:-

```
namespace <Company>\<Module>\Block\Adminhtml\Tab\Log;
class Grid 
extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{

    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \<Company>\<Module>\Model\ResourceModel\Log\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \<Company>\<Module>\Model\ResourceModel\Log\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $this->_logger->info($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

And remember that the collection factory is a magic class that can attaches to every class as Magento 1 wasn't complicated enough.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1-

```
$result_colletion = print_r($collection->getSelect()); 
Mage::log($$result_colletion, null, custom_collection.log,true);
```

Step 2-

After that Login into magento admin section and enable to log setting . Please see below .

```
System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings
```

Step 3-

After that see the log file `custom_collection.log` in `var/log/` folder .

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection();

    echo $products->getSelect();
```